# aurelia.globalizeResources no longer available

Tags: aurelia

Is `aurelia.globalizeResources`no longer available during main configuration stage? What is alternative way to register global resources in aurelia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method has been renamed to `globalResources`:

`globalResources(resources: string | string[]): FrameworkConfiguration;`